# the security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, request-digest

I am making a POST request to Sharepoint List and in that I have to add items more than 150 which takes my like 45-50 mins to add all the Line details. And once I have added I click on submit and then I got to network tab  i see error. Below is my code for adding those 150 items.

```
 if ($("#tbodyRAssetMaterial")[0].children.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < $("#tbodyRAssetMaterial")[0].children.length; i++) {
                RSrNo = $("#lblRSrNo" + itemCount).text();
                RAssetNo = $("#txtRAssetNo" + itemCount).val();
                RDescriptionOfItems = $("#txtRDescriptionOfItems" + itemCount).val();
                RQuantity = $("#txtRQuantity" + itemCount).val();
                RUnit = $("#txtRUnit" + itemCount).val();
                RDateOfReturn = moment($("#dtRDateOfReturn" + itemCount).val()).format(
                    "YYYY-MM-DD"
                );
                RRemarks = $("#txtRRemarks" + itemCount).val();
                var quantity = 0;
                sumOfTotalQuantity = parseFloat(sumOfTotalQuantity) + parseFloat(RQuantity);
                $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                        "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ASMGP')/items",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        __metadata: {
                            type: GetItemTypeForListName("ASMGP"),
                        },
                        Title: RSrNo,
                        AssetNo: RAssetNo,
                        DescriptionOfItems: RDescriptionOfItems,
                        Quantity: RQuantity,
                        Unit: RUnit,
                        ExpectedDateOfReturn: RDateOfReturn,
                        GatePassMasterID: itemId.toString(),
                        GatePassIdId: itemId,
                        Remarks: RRemarks,
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "X-HTTP-Method": "POST",
                    },
                    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    alert("Your Gatepass Created Successfully. Serial No.: " + NewSrNo);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        //$(".page-loader").addClass("d-none");
                    },
                });
               itemCount++;
            }
            UpdateSumOfTotalQuantity(itemId, sumOfTotalQuantity, NewSrNo);
       }

    }

the security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.
```

As per google's suggestion i have also added "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), in Headers section, still Im unable to to do the POST request. Im trying on SharePoint Online.
Please help, any suggestion will be appreciated.!!!

Answer (score 0):

When add items to sharepoint by restapi. metadata should be like following

```
  __metadata:
            {
                // Format of the "type" is: SP.Data.<<ListName>>ListItem
                type: "SP.Data.ASMGPListItem"
            }
```

headers should be like following

```
headers:
        {
            // Accept header: Specifies the format for response data from the server.
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            //Content-Type header: Specifies the format of the data that the client is sending to the server
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            // X-RequestDigest header: When you send a POST request, it must include the form digest value in X-RequestDigest header
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
```

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.